# How can we deploy schema and table changes as part of our Airflow workflow?

Tags: airflow

We periodically author new DAGs which in turn require new schema and tables in Redshift. Currently we manually create these schema and their tables via direct interaction with Redshift. This obviously isn't ideal. We'd like to automate this process and ideally bake it into our workflow when building out new DAGs.

How can we do this with Airflow?

Answer (score 1):

To suite with your requirement, I have some idea come out:

- Using Redshift JDBC, write some scripts to execute queries in any languages you feel comfortable.
- Create new Airflow Dags and call above script, maybe using BashOperator, PythonOperator
- About migration scripts, you can freely control them. Possibly sql files, or migration files managed by any frameworks.

Comment: I would suggest using a migration tool (we use alembic), and applying migrations on each deployment via a CI/CD pipeline.